# Will most IC's operate at 100C

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy

I'm thinking about making a self contained Bluetooth LE temperature sensor. I'd like it to be usable up to the boiling point of water. All the BTLE device seem to be rated up to 85C. Do you think they would operate at 100C?

Comment: Why not find one with an industrial or automotive range to begin with?

Comment: 100°C \$T_A \ne \$ 100°C \$T_J \$ .. the chip inside may be a lot hotter than the ambient. It's a crap shoot. For some applications it's worth qualifying chips yourself to high temperatures (eg. 150°C). This does not sound like it is one of those applications.

Comment: If the manufacturer doesn't think they'll operate at 100C, why do you think that we'd think that they might???

Comment: Done market analysis and have a need for a large quantity? Contact an application engineer from one of the major manufacturers. See if they can help you with a custom solution, but again, volume.

Comment: Paraphrasing what Dave Tweed says - if the manufacturer says 85C then they are missing a slice of the market not stating 100C - manufacturers are just not that daft.

Comment: @DaveTweed - 85C is a very standard max temperature that many devices list as their max. I believe it is considered "Industrial" if it can handle up to 85C. I bet many companies don't even test their products for consistent functionality above 85C because 85C is good enough and most customers don't need temps above that, so they don't want to waste their time. It's the same reason that you don't see temperatures like 86, 87, 91, etc, listed. They just get above a certain line and call it good enough. Also, most devices list storage temps of 125C so operating at 100 seems reasonable.

Comment: @Andyaka - See my comment above to DaveTweed.

Comment: A storage temperature of 125C means **nothing** about operation above 85C. If the datasheet only specifies operation to 85C then you know **nothing** about operation above that temperature. You **cannot** extrapolate from the datasheet based simply on what you want to be reality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, what do **I** think? I would lay better than even odds that most samples of such a chip will be functional at 15°C over the guaranteed range, possibly not quite meeting specifications in one way or another.

However, my guess and $2 will almost get you a coffee. If it's a student project or some hobby thing, and it doesn't really matter, YOLO. Be sure to use a battery that won't explode - many are rated for as low as 60°C.

If you're going to exceed the recommendations in some way, try to stay conservative or near nominal in **all** other ways (keep the supply voltage regulated tightly near nominal, reduce clock speeds below the maximum if possible etc.) They don't really test the chips at high temperature, they infer operation at temperature extremes from the *margins* that they can measure an ambient. IOW, if a flip-flop will operate at 125MHz at 25°C, they know that they can guarantee a 100MHz spec (say) at 125°C (even at supply voltage extremes), so it passes. That's why "overclocking" sometimes works.

Comment: One word edit - I assumed that you were not talking about fast sewing machines :-).

Comment: Goodness, thanks, Russell. Though I'd like to have one of those things.

Answer (score 2):

It's never a good idea to exceed the IC manufacturer's recommended operating conditions. You may get away with it with some devices from certain batches, but units from another production run will likely fail or operate flakey. It's a crap shoot.

Look into the LM75B. This is an I2C interface temperature sensor with an operating temperature range of -55 to +125 degC. Its measuring range includes 100 degC.

Still, you'll have to exercise prudent design practices to make this chip work reliably as you flirt with its upper specified operating temperature ( 125 degC ) while you are exposing it to a 100 degC measurement condition. (For one thing, you must ensure its die temperature doesn't exceed 125 degC with the body of the IC package at 100 degC, by taking into account the power dissiation of the die and the thermal resistance characteristics of the IC package. It might be possible, only a rigorous numeric analysis will tell ! )